# Button is not removing the textField & itself from super view in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitextfield

I am generating a `textField` and a remover `Button` in my view for generating both I have defined a function `pressedTextAction` and for removing them from view I have defined the function `pressedTextDestAction` and assigned to Button `textDest` but the problem is when I generate multiple textFields & button and when I click on remover button that is `textDest` it removes only last textField and button added to view and rest of the `textDest` do not work they are not removing the textField and buttons.

Here is other remover buttons cant remove the textField and itself buttons.

[image]

Here is the code

```
@objc func pressedTextAction(_ sender: UITextField) {
    self.textFieldElement = "textField1"

    self.updateScrollY()

    textFieldTag += 1
    textDestTag += 1
    uniY += 60
    //let textY = self.uniY + 20

    self.sampleTextField =  UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: self.xValue, y: uniY, width: 200, height: 30))
    self.sampleTextField.placeholder = "Enter placeholder"
    self.sampleTextField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
    self.sampleTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.roundedRect
    self.sampleTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
    self.sampleTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
    self.sampleTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
    self.sampleTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.whileEditing;
    self.sampleTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.center
    self.sampleTextField.delegate = self as? UITextFieldDelegate
    self.sampleTextField.tag = self.textFieldTag
    print("\(String(describing: self.sampleTextField.tag))")
    self.view.addSubview(self.getFormView)
    self.getFormView.addSubview(self.sampleTextField)
    let frametext = self.sampleTextField.frame.size.height
    self.textObjects?.append(self.sampleTextField as Any)
    self.yValue = self.yValue + Int(frametext) + 20
    self.xValue = 20
    print("You have text field with tag \(self.sampleTextField.tag)")

    let yOftextDest = uniY
    self.textDest = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: self.xValue + 220, y: yOftextDest + 5, width: 20, height: 20))
    self.textDest.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "destroyIcon"), for: .normal)
    self.getFormView.addSubview(textDest)

    self.textDest.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressedTextDestAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.textDest.tag = self.textDestTag
    print("\(String(describing: self.textDest.tag))")
    self.textDestObjects?.append(self.textDest as Any)
    self.enterPlaceholder()


}



@objc func pressedTextDestAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.updateScrollY()
    self.sampleTextField.viewWithTag(sampleTextField.tag)?.removeFromSuperview()
    self.textDest.viewWithTag(textDest.tag)?.removeFromSuperview()

}
```

Comment: You are trying to find the same view from it's tag and then removing it from superview. Why don't you use `self.sampleTextField.removeFromSuperview()` and `self.textDest.removeFromSuperview()`

Comment: @Mukesh I have used this but it does not work it also remove last generated textField and itself buttojn

Comment: these are subview of `getFormView` so you should use `self.getFormView.viewWithTag(sampleTextField.tag)?.removeFromSuperview()` and `self.getFormView.viewWithTag(textDest.tag)?.removeFromSuperview()`

Comment: @Mukesh getting this error Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'removeFro‌​mSuperview'

Comment: I think the issue might be with assigning a tag with += 1. Try to have  a global reference to the last tag you added like. `var lastTag: Int = 0`, then when creating a button increment this variable. And assign value of this variable to the tag of the created field.

Comment: @inokey I have done that already but is removes only last time generated textField and button itself

Comment: @iOSDeveloper this happens because you assign the value to the same variable every time `pressedTextAction` is executed. You continue to reuse the same variables. The solution here is to have reference to every textField you create. As far as I can see from the code, the easiest way to do so is to have an array of textfields. The index of the textfield in array should match it's tag.

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is to use a UITableView with custom cell that has a textField and a destructive button. That way you can easily add and remove new textFields, without explicitly having a reference to every textField.

On your `pressedTextDestAction` you could just remove the row form the table and dataSource and be sure you delete the right textField.

It could look something like this

```
var placeholders: [String]

/*...*/

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = YourCustomCell() //dequeued 
     cell.textField.text = placeholders[indexPath.row]
     cell.destructiveButton.tag = indexPath.row
     cell.destructiveButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressedTextDestAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
     return cell
}
```

Now in your method:

```
@objc func pressedTextDestAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
     table.removeRows(at: [IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)], with .fade)
     placeholders.removeAt(sender.tag)
}
```

I recommend you too look carefully into UITableViews or UICollectionViews as they really help you to manage reusable items. Moreover this is the preferred method to do so in iOS environment.

Comment: is there any way to work with uiviews instead of tableview

Comment: Create a custom UIView that will contain your textfield and button. When creating a new textfield, instead create this custom UIVIew and add it to array of views that you store globally in your viewController. When destructive button is tapped, iterate through array of your views to find the one with required tag. Remove that UIView from super view and delete it from array.